# Jboss 7.1 logging filter in standalone.xml

Tags: jboss

In Jboss 7.1 how to configure standalone.xml to log only INFO level

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
<level name="INFO"/>
<formatter>
<pattern-formatter pattern="%z{utc}%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n"/>
</formatter>
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
<suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default root loggers are configured to print INFO level logs. If you have to change log level for any other logger category or log handlers. Just add below tag to that particular category or handler.

```
<level name="INFO"/>
```

If you have log only INFO level logs, you will have t0 implement filter something like

```
<filter-spec value="(levels(INFO))"/>
```

Comment: When INFO here, it logs INFO level plus all above levels. I am trying to get only INFO not above levels like ERROR.

Comment: You will have to use log filters for that. Something like                         <filter-spec value="(levels(INFO))"/>